Empty outcome baking vertex color to texture
I have two ply files produced from point cloud, and I need to extract the texture from the vertex color. I follow videos found on Youtube. It worked the first time, but failing when I move on to the second one. I'm not sure where went wrong.
Here is the video of my wrokflow:
https://youtu.be/KR6wQfg86Oo
and here is my blender files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rJkU339mysj7As1GMIRAxpQXREDJk7P9?usp=sharing
"見返坂隧道-整條" is the one that work
"造橋隧道-整條01" is the one that fail
I've just started using blender for a week, so really grateful for this platform and anyone up here giving me some solutions~ Thanks in advanced!!

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Thank you for the advice! I’ll improve it~
